# Game where you allocate troops to battle fields

Tags: game-theory

**Alice and Bob each have 9 soldiers. There are 4 battle fields. Each player sends a non-negative integer number of soldiers to each battle field, and whoever has strictly more wins that battle field(if they send the same number, neither wins). The player that wins 3 or more battle fields gets a payoff of 1, and in all other cases gets a payoff of 0. What strategy should be played?**

I remember this game from a math tournament event, but nobody explained the solution afterwards. I am completely lost with this problem. Here is what I know so far:

Notation: $(a,b,c,d)$, $a+b+c+d=9$ means put $a$ soldiers in battle field $1$, $b$ in field $2$, etc.

1. Never allocate all $9$ soldiers onto two fields, since you will never win.
2. Never allocate $(0, 1, 1, 7)$, since you can win only if the other plays $(x, 0, 0, <7)$, which by 1 is never optimal.
3. Never allocate $(1, 1, 1, 6)$ by the same reasoning as above.
4. Let $(a, b, c, d), 0 \leq a \leq b \leq c \leq d, a+b+c+d=9$ be an allocation of troops.
   Then $a+b+c \leq 6$, and so $(a+1, b+1, c+1, 6-a-b-c)$ beats $(a,b,c,d)$. So there's no allocation that beats all others.
5. $(2, 2, 2, 3)$ is only beaten by $(3, 3, 3, 0)$
6. $(1, 2, 3, 3)$ is only beaten by $(2, 3, 4, 0), (2, 3, 0, 4)$
7. $(3, 3, 3, 0)$ is only beaten by $(4, 4, 0, 1), (4, 0, 4, 1),(0, 4, 4, 1)$
8. $(4, 4, 1, 0)$ is only beaten by $(5, 0, 2, 2), (5, 0, 3, 1), (5, 1, 2, 1)$ [and swapping 0 and 5]

All possibilities (not including permutations) are:
$$(0, 1, 2, 6), (0, 1, 3, 5), (0, 1, 4, 4), (0, 2, 2, 5), (0, 2, 3, 4), (0, 3, 3, 3)\\
(1, 1, 2, 5), (1, 1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 2, 4), (1, 2, 3, 3)\\
(2, 2, 2, 3)$$

Comment: I don't have the complete solution yet, but I have a suggestion. You should never play $(1,2,2,4)$, because playing $(2,2,2,3)$ is always better. The reason is that if you play $(2,2,2,3)$, the only way you lose is if the opponent plays $(3,3,3,0)$. If you play $(1,2,2,4)$, then you still lose against $(3,3,3,0)$, but in addition, you lose to $(2,3,3,1)$. I'm sure that a lot of the possibilities can be eliminated like this.

Comment: Actually, my previous comment could be an oversimplification, since $(1,2,2,4)$ defeats things that $(3,3,3,0)$ doesn't.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blotto_game for some background.